# Counting in hibernate using Criteria without unnecessary inner joins

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate, criteria

I am using criteria for counting number of rows.
consider a class

```
class GroupMembership{
 public Group  Group{get;set;}
 public Member Member{get;set;}

}
```

I have a criteria which fetches distinct members for each group as:

```
DetachedCriteria.For<GroupMembership>("this")
.CreateCriteria("Group", "grp")
.CreateAlias("this.CommunityMember", "CommunityMember")
.SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
.Add(Projections.GroupProperty("this.Group.Id"),"GroupId") 
.Add(Projections.CountDistinct("this.CommunityMember.Id"), "TotalMembers"))
```

Is there a way i can count without performing the inner join with the CommunityMember.

UPDATE: 
I am adding the SQLs generated from the query

```
SELECT   this_.GroupId                                  as y0_,
         count(distinct communitym2_.CommunityMemberId) as y1_
FROM     [GroupMembership] this_
         inner join [CommunityMember] communitym2_
           on this_.CommunityMemberId = communitym2_.CommunityMemberId
         inner join [Group] grp1_
           on this_.GroupId = grp1_.GroupId
GROUP BY this_.GroupId
```

As you can see we can easily avoid the inner join in the SQL. My question is whether the same can be done in criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about...

```
DetachedCriteria.For<GroupMembership>()
                .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
                    .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("Group"))
                    .Add(Projections.CountDistinct("CommunityMember")))
```